# User profile service for sharepoint 2016 internet facing sites

Tags: sharepoint

Please I want know if the user profile service is needed when configuring SharePoint 2016 internet facing sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not needed when you are going to configure SP 2016 internet facing site(s).

Its only needed when you want to use the Social features like My Sites, social tagging and newsfeeds etc.

Reference - [Overview of the User Profile service architecture in SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662538(v=office.16).aspx)